# SoundCloud API getting tracks favorites

Tags: api, statistics, soundcloud

Is it possible to know, who and when likes your track through SoundCloud API?

I can see this list on http://soundcloud.com/%usernick%/%track-name%/stats/who/favorites?from_date=2012-01-01&to_date=2012-06-09

Days statistics of favorites i can see it http://soundcloud.com/%usernick%/%track-name%/stats/counts/favorites?from_date=2012-01-01&to_date=2012-06-09

But how i can get it through API?

I except this info on GET `/tracks/%track_id%/favorites.json` or GET `/users/user_id/favorites/%track_id%.json`, but it isn't working.

Note: This is feature only for paid user.

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I found only one way -- through `/my/activity/`, but in this case i must to get all my activity of all tracks, comments and favorites.